# Get 30 days prior data for each row of query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query where I have a list of ~ 20k users for a specific week of the month that represents that they have logged on to our site.

What I need to get - for each of these users, in the past 30 days if they have 
1. logged on: defined by any rows recorded in the same table
2. max event in the 30 day window, prior to the date in the current where clause

This is the current code snippet that helps me narrow to the ~20k users for a given week to begin with:

```
select
   user_id,
   max(timestamp)
from table 
   where timestamp between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-05'
group by 1,2;
```

Expected result set/columns:

1. user_id,
2. max(timestamp),
3. logged_on, [if they have any # of rows in the same table within 30 days prior to their max(timestamp) date]
4. previous_timestamp, [the 2nd most recent login date within 30 days prior to their max(timestamp) date]

Comment: It would help to have the schema of the table, and a few sample rows, including a few rows that can illustrate what the answer should be.

One difficulty will be showing users that have not logged on, as they won't have records for the date window, I think.

Comment: Is there a single "max" date, or a max date per user?

Comment: @BobMcCormick - Thanks. The other columns in this table are all URL/Traffic related. When a user logs in, the user_id column is populated with a value. If the user is not logged in, that column will be NULL. I intend to filter out NULL rows to only look at logged in users.

There is no single "max" date per user. I'm applying the max function to the timestamp bound by the week of users I wont to profile and begin with.

Comment: I think you need to provide a concrete example of a few rows of the table, with only the columns of interest.    Also, what query have you tried so far?

Comment: Here are the columns of the table, with 2 sample values in parentheses:
1. user_id (A1B2C3; NULL)
2. timestamp (2019-02-01 10:56:35.044; 2019-02-02 09:50:34.045)
3. url (www.page1.com; www.page2.com)
4. source (facebook; twitter)

Using this data set, I am currently filtering only on one week's worth of data to get the list of UserIDs. For this subset of users, 30D prior to the one week of data (mentioned above), looking to get:

1. number of rows 
2. if the source column for any of those rows contained 'facebook'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Not sure if it's the most efficient method though - perhaps windowing functions may perform better but like bob-mccormick mentioned: the tricky bit would be filling in dates where the user (partition key) was not active so that the range query will work correctly.

**Example data setup (Snowflake syntax)**

```
-- Create sample table
create temporary table user_logins (userid number, date_logged_on timestamp);
;

-- Insert some random sample data
insert overwrite into user_logins 
select 
    uniform(1,10,random()) userid, 
    dateadd('minutes', uniform(1,86400,random()) * -1,current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz) date_logged_on 
from table(generator(rowcount => 100))
;
```

**Select statement**

```
-- Run select
with user_last_logins as (
  select 
    userid,
    max(date_logged_on) last_login
  from user_logins
  where
    date_logged_on between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-08'
  group by userid
)
select 
    user_last_logins.userid,
    max(user_last_logins.last_login) last_logged_on,
    count(prior_30_each_user.userid) num_logins_prior_30,
    max(prior_30_each_user.date_logged_on)
from user_last_logins
left join user_logins prior_30_each_user
    on user_last_logins.userid = prior_30_each_user.userid
    and prior_30_each_user.date_logged_on > dateadd('day', -30, user_last_logins.last_login) and prior_30_each_user.date_logged_on < user_last_logins.last_login
group by  user_last_logins.userid
;
```

Comment: Thanks @SimonD - that worked! Appreciate the help here.